# AVRDUDE Android Arduino ioctl error

Tags: android, arduino, avr, avrdude

My previous question, *[Android cannot talk to Arduino using AVRDUDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596376/android-cannot-talk-to-arduino-using-avrdude/15596858?noredirect=1#15596858)*, has been resolved. I can now connect my [Nexus 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7) to my Arduino Uno. The full command I am running is this:

```
/system/xbin/su (getting root here)
/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/local/bin/avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/bus/usb/002/002  -b 115200 -C /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/local/etc/avrdude.conf -U flash:w:led.hex
```

Here I am trying to put the hex file on the Arduino. I do however get the following error:

> avrdude: ser_open():can't set attributes for device "/dev/bus/usb/002/002": Inappropriate ioctl for device ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Bad file desriptor

Comment: I am uploading the file from my mac, and I get:

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "led.hex"
avrdude: input file led.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (214 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.04s

Comment: On Android I upload exactly the same file, so the led.hex file itself is 100% correct.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out I was using the wrong port. I used `/dev/bus/usb/002/002` while I should have used `ttyACM0`.

Comment: How to know "tty"-like name for /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY device name ?