# Run avrdude on Android with Samsung devices

Tags: android, avrdude

Hi members of stackoverflow.com!

I try to build an app in Android that can upload HEX file generated by avr-gcc. I installed the AndAVR this chaintool http://code.google.com/p/andavr/

to run avrdude (in root devices with USB-OTG cable) I use this command in mobile terminal:

```
/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/local/bin/avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p m2560 -P /dev/bus/usb/002/001  -b 115200 -C /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/local/etc/avrdude.conf -U flash:w:/sdcard/megademo/Blink1.cpp.hex
```

and after Read this post [Android cannot talk to Arduino using AVRDUDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596376/android-cannot-talk-to-arduino-using-avrdude) I try the solution and change the /dev/bus/usb/002/002 by /dev/ttyACM0.

```
/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/local/bin/avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p m2560 -P /dev/ttyACM0  -b 115200 -C /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/local/etc/avrdude.conf -U flash:w:/sdcard/megademo/Blink1.cpp.hex
```

But avrdude answer me with:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "unkown". No such file or directory.
```

I have a Arduino Mega 2560 and Mega ADK 2560 R3, both boards have a ATmega2560 microcontollers and I have a:

- Samsumg Galaxy S2 run Android 4.1.2 stock with root
- Samsumg Galaxy S3    run Android 4.1.2 stock with root
- Samsumg Galaxy Tab Note 10.1 run Android 4.1.2 stock without root
- Asus Transfomer Pad TF700T run Android 4.2.1 stock without root

the problem is that Samsung devices doesn't enumerate the Arduino board and the Asus tab yes.

In all devices I run the command in mobile terminal:

```
cat /proc/tty/drivers
```

and Asus present the specific driver:

```
ACM /dev/ttyACM 166 0-31 serial
```

this driver doesn't show in Samsung devices, well this driver is essential to upload the hex file to Arduino board, so How can I install this driver in Samsung devices? or how can I upload the hex file?

Android in all devices create a file in /dev/bus/USB/002/xxx where xxx is the Arduino board or other USB device.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this method, you need to load the cdc_acm kernel module - which probably was not supplied with your device, so you will have to build it.  And then create the corresponding /dev/ttyACM0 device node, since the daemon that would do that on a desktop linux probably isn't there.  You will need root to do these things, and moderately close kernel sources to compile from.

Another approach might be to implement CDC_ACM type communication in user mode from an Android app using the Android USB Host APIs if those are supported on your device.  This would be a more "android style" solution, but would require some changes to avrdude, since it will have to do communication via an Android-aware backend service packaged in an app.

Also note that CDC_ACM is used by the recent arduinos (Uno, etc) and a minority of clones; older Arduino boards and the majority of clones use FTDI USB-serial converters and require ftdi driver modules or protocols.

Comment: I found a driver called cdc_acm.ko for S3 in this page: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1113&sid=8a884c8da0544520e912d4e3aa94351b

 I installed and this works, how I use this driver in other device? is it  possible?

I installed with the command with super user:

# insmod /sdcard/cdc-acm.ko

Comment: Kernel modules tend to only work on the same/very close kernel builds.  Even it if works, to use it you will need to create a device node.  You can probably get the major/minor numbers with ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 from your tablet where it works (probably 166 and 0 based on your above).  First read a linux man page for `mknod` then realize that Android's `mknod` may be weird but you can likely see comparable example of using it in the startup scripts on your device.

Comment: I will implement the STK500V2 protocol in java to upload hex file to Arduino Mega 2560  with the USB-Serial API for Android to make my application "general" and without access root thanks for help me!

Best regards!

Comment: @MiguelTresPatines, did you end up implementing this in java?